# Magento 1.9.0.1 Import error: "0 in rows: 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5 ecc"

Tags: magento

I'm trying to import my products and this error appear.

```
    0 in rows: 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10, 11, 11, 13, 13, 14, 14, 15, 15, 16, 16, 17, 17, 19, 19, 21, 21, 22, 22, 24, 24, 26, 26, 28, 28, 29, 29, 30, 30, 32, 32, 33, 33, 35, 35, 36, 36, 37, 37, 38, 38, 39, 39, 40, 40, 41, 41, 42, 42, 43, 43, 44, 44, 45, 45, 47, 47, 49, 49, 50, 50, 52, 52, 54, 54, 55, 55
Orphan rows that will be skipped due default row errors in rows: 12, 18, 20, 23, 25, 27, 31, 34, 46, 48, 51, 53, 56, 57
```

With an older version of my site the import works fine. What this error mean?

I'm not using dataflow or extension, i'm using default magento import

here the example
[Link google document](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13Ot02e9cpJpiAuVlZIR4FMSXADM0S6puDASpAx3CT2s/edit?usp=sharing)

thx

Comment: How are you importing, through some extension? If you can provide a few lines of your csv file with headers in the question some one may be able to help you.

Comment: Are you importing from magento import/export, Dataflow profile or some other extension. probably as per error, you were tried from System > Import/Export > Import. Please provide few rows of csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the error was caused by 3 colums: msrp_display_actual_price_type,msrp_enabled,options_container but I do not understand why :( .
In the old version of website this error doesnt appear